# GDB Getting the correct stop point when breakpoint set on variable declaration

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

Given the following code sippet:

```
1:    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
2:       int i;
3:    
4:       i = i + 1;
5:    
6:       ...
7:    
8:    }
```

When you set a breakpoint on line 2: in the above code and start debugging in GDB the execution actually stops on line 4:.  This is the correct behavior of course BUT is it possible to query GDB for the correct stop point number **before** debugging... right after the creation of the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(gdb) b 2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400547: file main.cpp, line 2.
```

This is what `info b` shows:

```
(gdb) info b $bpnum
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000400547 in main(int, char**) at main.cpp:2
```

and you need to do this for address in the column "Address":

```
(gdb) info line *0x0000000000400547
Line 4 of "main.cpp" starts at address 0x400547 <main(int, char**)+11> and ends at 0x400550 <main(int, char**)+20>.
```

As you can see the real breakpoint on "Line 4 of main.cpp"

Comment: Not bad, hadn't thought of tickling it out this way. +1. Anyway, going to leave my answer, as I think the intention was more likely to set a watch point.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for

```
info b
```

(which is short for `info breakpoints`) and gives the number in the first "column".

If you want to break when the variable gets modified, use a **watch point** instead. GDB will always break at the nearest executable code line after the breakpoint (if set by line). A variable declaration isn't executable code and therefore the assignment on the next (non-empty) line will be used.

If what you are looking for is to know at exactly which line it stops, I think there is no such thing on the GDB prompt. However, you can still use a watch point and customize what happens on your break and watch points using `commands`.

---

From the comment skwllsp wrote, here's how it would look:

```
(gdb) info b
Num    Type       Disp  Enb Address            What
1      breakpoint keep  y   0x0000000000400547 in main(int, char**) at main.cpp:2
```

Which says there is one breakpoint (`1`), which is enabled and it shows you the line, too. Disposition (Disp) and enabled (Enb) are useful, but please read the manual for a proper description. I can also warmly recommend the book "Art of Debugging" from Nostarch.

Comment: Seems it doesn't work as you write: `(gdb) info b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000400547 in main(int, char**) at main.cpp:2
`

Comment: @skwllsp: added that to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand @user1883815 wanted to see main.cpp:4 in this situation and your command still shows main.cpp:2

Comment: @skwllsp: there is no such thing on the GDB prompt, as I also try to convey in my explanation. I am also giving him the alternative of what he's more likely to want. Why would anyone set a bpx on a *declaration* if it wasn't meant as a **watch point** in the first place?